# Traducción de "meta" referido a los sitios meta de Stack Exachange network

Tags: traducción

¿Cual sería una traducción de la palabra "*Meta*" con referencia a los sitios meta de la red de Stack Exchange? Yo puedo inferir por el mismo link que ponen ellos en su pagina de [about us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-discussion) que es refirido a *Meta discussion*, como que el principal objetivo del sitio es discutir como funcionan los sitios hijos por decirlos de alguna manera. ¿Cómo se podria decir esto en español?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Meta", tal y como se utiliza en inglés, viene del griego "meta" como en "metafísica", que era un libro de Aristóteles que no tenía nombre propio sino que se situaba "al lado de" su libro de Física. El sentido actual es lo que está al lado de algo, o que hace referencia a algo sin ser parte. Así, la metafísica no es física, los jugadores de rol hacen metajuego cuando utilizan conocimientos que sus personajes no tienen, y, en este caso particular, el sitio Meta de Stack Exchange es el sitio que está al lado de los demás sitios, como información adicional a ellos, y para discusión *sobre* los sitios, no *dentro de* ellos.

Creo que lo mejor es dejarlo como "Meta".

Answer (score 2):

La traducción es la misma, *meta*, de la raíz griega "[meta-](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=meta)":

> 1. elem. compos. Significa 'junto a', 'después de', 'entre' o 'con'.
>      *Metacentro, metatórax*